# VBA to copy the value from Google Analytics [opened in IE] site to Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have done few VBA + IE connections before, especially with regards to selecting different buttons and lists [including automated data inputs e.g. for logins, date, and so on]. However, I have not done copying of specific data from the IE to excel before.

The question is how to extract this data from the IE to excel. Namely the number 257 (which changes everyday). The additional issue is the structure of the IE page [which is Google Analytics]. Before you advise me that I can use "Export" on GA page, please note I have majority of my options blocked. Also google drive and google docs are out of the equation.

The part of the source code is:

```
<div class="_GAlF _GALn">P R R</div>
<div class="_GAef" id="ID-layout-1536671725872"><div class="_GANY"><div class="_GAxN"><img width="75" height="18" class="_GANU" alt="" src="s/cleardot.gif"></div><div><div class="_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6">257</div></div><div><span class="_GAkhb">% of Total:</span> <span class="_GAvQb">0.04%</span> <span class="_GAqs">(601,038)</span></div></div></div>
<div class="_GANY"><div class="_GAxN"><img width="75" height="18" class="_GANU" alt="" src="s/cleardot.gif"></div><div><div class="_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6">257</div></div><div><span class="_GAkhb">% of Total:</span> <span class="_GAvQb">0.04%</span> <span class="_GAqs">(601,038)</span></div></div>
<div class="_GAxN"><img width="75" height="18" class="_GANU" alt="" src="s/cleardot.gif"></div>
<div><div class="_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6">257</div></div>
<div class="_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6">257</div>
```

cleaner screenshot:

[image]

Can the value be perhaps identified through the "ID-layout", which seems to be unique to this particular box? Yet that would have to descend to the area which holds the value of 257 anyway. Please advise. Thank you.

That's what I get Q:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML shown you could attempt to narrow down with parent id and local class attribute selector combination

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1) =  ie.document.querySelector("#ID-layout-1536671725872 [class='_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6']").innerText
```

Not all the selector shows in the query box below but this is the result:

[image]

The id selector is added to try and localize the class selector, given the small HTML sample. The `"#"` is id CSS selector and `"[]"` is the attribute selector.

The selector combination is applied via the `.querySelector` method of document. Provided you are using above IE8 this should work fine.

---

If the page is not JS heavy/slow loading you may be able to ditch IE opening for issuing an XMLHTTP request:

```
Dim html As New HTMLDocument  '<==Tools > references > add reference to microsoft html object library
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1) = .querySelector("#ID-layout-1536671725872 [class='_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6']").innerText
    End With
End With
```

Comment: I'll work on it and update you - from my initial test it seems to work (hence vote up). Unfortunately I cannot provide the link, apologies.

Comment: QHarr can you please clarify how can this value of 257 be transferred to the excel file (which is the file with your code in it) (any sheet/any cell). Thank you

Comment: I get an "object required" at this line:  .body.innerHTML = sResponse PS. I have replaced the "URL" with the actual URL. Do I need to do anything with "GET"?

Comment: Somehow my "Tools" are greyed-out. I cannot add HTMLDoc to MSFT library.

Comment: Sorted. Now I get an error in line "ThisWorkbook...": Run Time Error 91 Object Variable

Comment: Can you next try then Dim ele As Object: Set ele = .querySelector("#ID-layout-1536671725872 [class='_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6']"):ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1) = ele.innerText, but where the : are, remove the : and place each bit on separate lines. The  see which line has error. E.g. Dim ele As Object would be one line, etc.... i.e. https://pastebin.com/p6rBJSdg

Comment: I get "invalid or unqualified reference" on .querySelector

Comment: you need the document part in front  so just put html.querySelector ....... for now.....  before we were working inside of With html  ..... statement

Comment: Now I get object variable error 91 at the line: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1) = ele.innerText right below Set ele...

Comment: ok.... so it is not finding an element by that selector which is possible when generating by XMLHTTP request for a javscript/Ajax page. To confirm, the IE version works right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180061/discussion-between-qharr-and-wheeliam).

Answer (score 1):

Is class "_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6" used only at this line?

If it is, this should work:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6")(0).innerText
```

Comment: Actually this is the problem, "_GAeS _GAHeb _GAA6" is used in other 6 windows (which I wanted to reference as well).